# Java profiling of a multithreaded app is showing java.lang.UNIXProcess as the hog

Tags: java, multithreading, profiling, fork

I am profiling a multithreaded Java app using `java -agentlib:hprof=cpu=samples ...`. It reports the following top traces (I removed #2 because it's irrelevant to this question):

```
TRACE 301119:
      java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(UNIXProcess.java:Unknown line)
      java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
      java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
      java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ...
TRACE 301113:
      java.lang.UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(UNIXProcess.java:Unknown line)
      java.lang.UNIXProcess.access$500(UNIXProcess.java:54)
      java.lang.UNIXProcess$4.run(UNIXProcess.java:227)
      java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)

1 25.90% 25.90%  109819 301119 java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec
...
3 17.87% 62.92%   75770 301113 java.lang.UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit
```

The only place in my code where `ProcessBuilder` is used is in this method that is invoked by every thread:

```
public ArrayList<String> runProcess(final String input)
{
    ArrayList<String> allRes = new ArrayList<String>();

    try
    {
        Process process = new ProcessBuilder("/foo/bar/prog1,"-foo",input).start();
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String res = ... // get result from line
            allRes.add(res);
        }

        return allRes;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }   

}
```

What would be likely reason(s) for the program to spend so much time in `java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec`? Also, I am not sure where `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker` is called from the 3rd trace. Is it invoked from withing my `runProcess()` method or elsewhere?

Here's a twist to this story: the reason why I started profiling in the first place is that one version of my code a lot slower than another. The difference between the two is NOT in whether they execute `runProcess()`. They both do. The difference is elsewhere. However, when I profile the faster version of my code, the two threads whown here don't appear anywhere near the top. So it looks as if a different place in my program triggers the issue with `java.lang.UNIXProcess` here. Or maybe there are two different problems that happen to cooccur because they are both related to, e.g., some sort of overarching multithreading problem that I am experiencing here.

Comment: Creating a Process is a very expensive resource. I would minimise the number of times per second you fork a new process.

Comment: I agree that a process is an very expensive resource.  If that ProcessBuilder is being called by every thread, that's the problem.  Try to re-write "prog1" as a Java method rather than a separate process, the code will be much faster.

Comment: The 2nd one is the actual thread that waits for the process while the foreground is free to continue after calling `ProcessBuild#start()`. see http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/UNIXProcess.java#327